# NoDriver calling acmFormatSuggest

Tags: c#, naudio

Please see my below code,

```
        if (fileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".wav"))
        {
            waveFileStream = OpenWavStream(fileName);
        }
        else if (fileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".mp3"))
        {
            waveFileStream = new Mp3FileReader(fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported extension");
        }
        var waveChannel = new SampleChannel(waveFileStream);
        this.SetVolumeDelegate = (vol) => waveChannel.Volume = vol;
        var postVolumeMeter = new MeteringSampleProvider(waveChannel);
        return postVolumeMeter;
```

I have used for MP3 player. When any machine the ACM Codecs not installed the following error is coming.

> "NoDriver calling acmFormatSuggest".

Please suggest how to install the ACM codecs in my machine.

Comment: Hi there, were you able to figure out a solution for this? I'm getting the same error, with no suggested resolutions working when deploying this into a 64 bit Win environment

Comment: I'm having this issue when switching between x86 and x64 machines running windows Server 2008 R2, the x86 is fine but the is x64 not working for me either

Comment: Same issue, works in x86 but not x64.  Any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows are you using? MP3FileReader tries to find an ACM MP3 decoder, which is supplied as standard with Windows XP, Vista & 7.

Comment: We are getting this issue till now with Windows XP and Windows server 2008 (Enterprise).

Comment: you'll probably have to seek out a free MP3 ACM decoder. There are a few of them about

Comment: Hi Mark,We tried with lot of free decoders, but still the same problem is coming. Can you please suggest which will help for me.

Comment: It works on my dev machine, but I'm having problems on Azure, where I can't install anything. Any chance to upload a binary and use it somehow?

Comment: yeah, if you have an ACM codec, you can use AcmAddDriver which NAudio has wrappers for